# Como comprimir código em python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Queria deixar esse pequeno trecho de código em uma única linha ...

```
i = int(input())
for j in range(1,i+1):
  if(i%j==0):
    print(j)
```

é possível ?

Comment: Já ouviu falar em list comprehension?

Comment: Uma questão importante: por que precisa que seja em uma linha, sendo que a leitura de um valor da entrada e a geração da lista de divisores são duas coisas completamente distintas?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss queria ver se conseguia diminuir o tempo de execução do código ...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters vou procurar sobre ...

Comment: A quantidade de linhas não está de todo relacionada com o tempo de execução do código

Comment: Escreva o código em C e reduzirá o tempo de execução. Se o problema é o tempo, e duvido que seja, então para um código tão simples só vejo esta solução. Eu poderia falar Assembly, mas duvido que alguém consiga fazer isso mais rápido que em C, e corre-se bem mais risco.

Comment: Em qualquer que seja a linguagem de programação que você trabalhar `sempre` existirá no `mínimo` "1" `input` e "1" `output`. Por isso, este código poderá ser reduzido no `máximo` em `"2"` linhas, o que você conseguirá, utilizando [List Comprehesion](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459254/d%C3%A1-para-fazer-o-for-em-1-linha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso, vamos usar funções *lambdas*, porém pode ficar tranquilo que é algo simples.

Podemos fazer por partes:

A variável `i` deixaremos para o final.

1. Primeiro compactamos o `if` e o `print`

   ```
   (lambda x,j: print(j) if x%j == 0 else None)
   ```
2. Depois compactamos o ciclo `for`, onde estiver escrito "Func", imagine que é uma função qualquer

   ```
   [ Func(xa,ja) for xa in range(1, ja+1)]
   ```
3. Agora precisamos pôr a função *lambda* que criamos dentro do ciclo `for` compactado. Então só substituir "Func" pelo *lambda*

   ```
   [ (lambda x,j: print(j) if x%j == 0 else None)(ja, xa) for xa in range(1, ja+1)]
   ```
4. Porém ainda temos que passar o nosso argumento de entrada, `i`, o *input*. Vamos construir uma nova função *lambda* para tal

   ```
   (lambda ja: [ (lambda x,j: print(j) if x%j == 0 else None)(ja,xa) for xa in range(1, ja+1)])
   ```
5. Agora só precisamos adicionar um *input* a ela

   ```
   (lambda ja: [ (lambda x,j: print(j) if x%j == 0 else None)(ja, xa) for xa in range(1, ja+1)])(int(input('Digite uma entrada : ')))
   ```

E pronto, tens tudo numa única linha, caso queira aprender mais, pode procurar por *"usando lambda no python"* ou *"programação funcional no python"*.

Algumas fontes que podem te auxiliar nos estudos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH8wDy8kWE8 (Português)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25ovCm9jKfA (Inglês)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3waZGETmzjY (inglês)

Comment: caraaaa .... muito bom (=

Comment: @CleefSouza , caso o alguma das resposta foi a que procura, marque como aceita, para sabermos que já esta resolvida. Se não, edite a pergunta com oque se precisa. Para podermos ajudar. Flw :)

Answer (score 6):

O que você pode fazer é reduzir e simplificar seu código com *list comprehension*:

```
i = int(input('Calcular divisores de: '))
divisores = [j for j in range(1, i+1) if i % j == 0]
print('Divisores:', divisores)
```

Menos que isso prejudicará a legibilidade e semântica do seu código: não misture a lógica de ler o valor da entrada com o cálculo de divisores.

Mas dado seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322075/como-comprimir-c%C3%B3digo-em-python-3?noredirect=1#comment652551_322075):

> queria ver se conseguia diminuir o tempo de execução do código ...

Faço minhas as [palavras do Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322075/como-comprimir-c%C3%B3digo-em-python-3?noredirect=1#comment652553_322075): quantidade de linhas não tem relação direta com tempo de execução do código.

Comment: Sobre tempo de execução, recomendo que você abra outra pergunta detalhando exatamente o que precisa para analisarmos melhor. Parece que a pergunta que fez aqui não reflete exatamente o que você quer fazer.

Comment: So falta o "em 1 linha" em honra do codegolf :D

Comment: boa, me ajudou bastante ... (=

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o *"one line converter"*, converte qualquer código python em uma linha só automaticamente:

https://onelinepy.herokuapp.com/

O seu código fica assim:

```
(lambda __y, __print, __g: [(lambda __after, __items, __sentinel: __y(lambda __this: lambda: (lambda __i: [(lambda __after: (__print(j), __after())[1] if ((i % j) == 0) else __after())(lambda: __this()) for __g['j'] in [(__i)]][0] if __i is not __sentinel else __after())(next(__items, __sentinel)))())(lambda: None, iter(range(1, (i + 1))), []) for __g['i'] in [(int(input()))]][0])((lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda: y(y)()))), __import__('__builtin__', level=0).__dict__['print'], globals())
```

O interessante é que isso serve pra provar que uma linha só é bobagem em python, a linguagem favorece códigos legíveis e não número de linhas.