# Como fazer o laço 'for' em 1 linha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

O seguinte código não funcionou:

```
rank = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(rank[c] for c in range(4))
```

Se tiver como fazer o uso do `for` em uma linha gostaria de saber.

Comment: André, procura por List Comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps, um exemplo: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/HappyLightgreenPortablesoftware

Comment: Obrigado,pela ajuda.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depende **muito** do que você quer fazer, e talvez nem precise do `for`.

Você quer simplesmente imprimir os elementos da lista? Então por que não fazer apenas `print(rank)`? Tudo bem que isso imprimirá `[1, 2, 3, 4]` e pode ser que você queira os elementos separados por algum outro caractere, e sem os colchetes. Se for o caso, pode fazer apenas assim:

```
print(*rank) # 1 2 3 4

# ou
print(' '.join(map(str, rank))) # 1 2 3 4
```

O primeiro caso usa a sintaxe de [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists): o asterisco diz que cada elemento da lista `rank` deve ser passado como parâmetro para `print`, ou seja, nesse caso é o mesmo que fazer `print(1, 2, 3, 4)`. O segundo caso usa [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para juntar os elementos da lista, separando-os por espaço (a desvantagem é que precisei usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para transformar os números em strings, senão `join` dá erro).

Se quiser mudar para imprimir cada elemento em uma linha (não dá para saber se era essa a intenção), basta mudar para:

```
print(*rank, sep='\n')

# ou
print('\n'.join(map(str, rank)))
```

---

Ou você quer **muito** usar um `for`, de qualquer jeito? Sinceramente, para o que *parece* ser a sua necessidade (só quer imprimir os elementos da lista), não precisa complicar. [Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/459255/112052) (que foi apagada) sugeriu fazer `[print(c) for c in rank]`, o que é uma gambiarra, na minha opinião. Isso porque, graças aos colchetes em volta da expressão, você está criando uma lista - e ela é criada à toa, pois não é guardada em nenhuma variável e só está aí para que o `print` seja chamado várias vezes. Mas se for assim, por que não usar um `for` simples?

```
for n in rank:
    print(n)
```

> "*Ah, mas não está em uma linha.*"

E daí? O que você deveria ter como objetivo é escrever código claro e sem complicações desnecessárias. Muitas vezes a tentativa de deixá-lo mais curto pode acabar deixando-o pior. [Código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052). E quantidade de linhas, ainda mais em um caso simples como esse, é um fator tão secundário que nem deveria ser uma preocupação.

Sei que muitas vezes pode parecer "legal" usar um recurso "esperto" da linguagem (como as tais [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps) que sugeriram), mas também acho importante entender que cada ferramenta tem o seu uso, e nem sempre você precisa usá-las. Se for só para imprimir os elementos da lista, na minha opinião não precisa. E querer forçar algum uso só para "ficar tudo em uma linha" me parece um uso errado do recurso.

---

Se você só quer fazer o "`for` em uma linha", também dá para trapacear:

```
for n in rank: print(n)
```

Sim, isso é equivalente a:

```
for n in rank:
    print(n)
```

Mas está em uma linha :-) <sup><sub>*desculpe, não resisti*</sub></sup>

Comment: Obrigado, pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Pra ter o `for` em uma linha, basta fazer:

```
print([rank for rank in range(4)])
```

Precisa colocar ele entre os colchetes "[" e "]" para funcionar, caso contrário irá ocorrer erro.

É possível ainda aplicar filtros, por exemplo:

```
print([rank for rank in range(4) if rank % 2 == 0])
```

Terá como saída apenas os números `pares`.

No python isso se chama `list comprehensions`

Answer (score 3):

Se realmente for necessário, dá sim para implementar não apenas **"1"** só **"for"**, mas também **"2"** ou **"3"** em apenas uma só linha.

Para isso devemos utilizar os conceitos de [List Comprehesions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps).

Se não for necessário utilizar a estrutura `"for"` podemos utilizar a função `"map"`, tal como os próximos três eexemplos.

1º Exemplo:

Trabalhando com os mesmos valores que você utilizou, podemos captura-los pelo teclado para serem inseridos na lista e, depois, exibi-los. Para isso devemos implementar o seguinte código...

```
lista = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(lista)
```

Na primeira linha deste código implementamos uma lista e, dentro dela, mapeamos a inserção de `"n"` valores inteiros separados por um espaço. Neste código, iremos capturar todos os valor a partir do teclado (digitando todos eles na mesma linha, separando-os por apenas um espaço). Desta forma, podemos implementar uma lista com um número indefinido de valores, podendo ser do tipo inteiro (int), real (float) ou cadeias de caracteres (strings). Para mudar o tipo de variável basta trocarmos o seu tipo, como por exemplo...

2º Exemplo:

```
lista = list(map(float, input().split()))
print(lista)
```

Neste exemplo substituímos o tipo `"int"` por `"float"`.

3º Exemplo:

```
lista = list(map(str, input().split()))
print(lista)
```

Neste caso, trocamos o tipo de variável numérica por string. O algoritmo continuará a funcionar.

Agora, se você de fato quer implementar muito uma instrução `"for"` em apenas uma só linha, você pode verificar os demais exemplos.

4º Exemplo:

```
lista = [item for item in range(1, 5)]
print(lista)
```

Com este algoritmo você consegue implementar uma lista formada por números inteiros começando de `"1"` até `"5 - 1"`, ou seja de `"1"` até `"4"`.

5º Exemplo:

```
lista = [item**2 for item in range(10)]
print(lista)
```

Este algoritmo cria e exibe uma lista formada pelos `"10"` primeiros quadrados perfeitos.

6º Exemplo:

```
lista = [item**3 for item in range(20)]
print(lista)
```

Este algoritmo cria e exibe uma lista formada pelos `"20"` primeiros cubos perfeitos.

7º Exemplo:

```
lista = [numero for numero in range(0, 21) if numero % 2 == 0]
print(lista)
```

Este algoritmo cria e exibe uma lista formada pelos `"primeiros"` números pares compreendidos entre `"0"` e `"20"`.

8º Exemplo:

```
lista = [numero for numero in range(0, 31) if numero % 2 != 0]
print(lista)
```

Este algoritmo cria e exibe uma lista formada pelos `"primeiros"` números ímpares compreendidos entre `"0"` e `"30"`.

9º Exemplo:

```
lista = [numero for numero in range(0, 101) if numero % 5 == 0 if numero % 6 == 0]
print(lista)
```

Este algoritmo cria e exibe uma lista formada pelos números compreendidos entre `"0"` e `"100"`, que são simultaneamente `"múltiplos"` de `"5"` e `"6"`.

10º Exemplo:

```
lista = ['1' if numero % 4 == 0 else '0' for numero in range(20)]
print(lista)
```

Este algoritmo cria e exibe uma lista com 20 elementos que contenha `"1"` quando determinado número for múltiplo de 4 e `"0"`, caso contrário.

11º Exemplo:

Quando necessário, podemos também inserir **"2"** estruturas **"for"** em uma única linha. Isso ocorre, quando queremos obter uma lista formada pelas combinações dos elementos de outras "duas" listas, quando os elementos forem diferentes...

```
lista = [(x, y) for x in range(1, 4) for y in range(1, 5) if x != y]
print(lista)
```

Neste caso, obtemos uma lista, na qual os elementos da mesma, são tuplas (delimitadadas por parênteses).

12º Exemplo:

Se pretendemos calcular o valor de `"pi"` com 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , n, casas decimais podermos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from math import pi
lista = [str(round(pi, i)) for i in range(1, 6)]
print(lista)
```

A partir deste algoritmo obtemos o valor de "pi" calculado com até "5" casas decimais.

13º Exemplo:

Se for o caso, também podemos inserir **"3"** estruturas **"for"** em uma mesma linha. Isso ocorre quando queremos obter uma lista formada pelas combinações dos elementos de outras "três" listas, quando os elementos forem diferentes...

```
lista = [(x, y, z) for x in range(1, 3) for y in range(1, 4) for z in range(1, 4) if x != y != z]
print(lista)
```

14º Exemplo:

Se quisermos montar uma lista formada pelos `"logaritmos neperianos"` de cada elemento de outra lista podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from math import log

lista = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12]
resultado = [round(log(item), 5) for item in lista]
print(resultado)
```

15º Exmplo:

Se quisermos montar uma lista formada pelas temperaturas em graus `"celsius"` de uma lista formada por temperaturas em graus `"fahrenheit"`, podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
fahrenheit = [32, 46, 55, 68, 73, 94, 98, 106]

celsius = [round(((5 * (item - 32)) / 9), 1) for item in fahrenheit]
print(celsius)
```

16º Exemplo:

Se desejarmos montar uma lista formada pelos valores de `"senos"` e `"cossenos"` dos ângulos, cujos valores estão em outra lista, podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from math import sin, cos, radians

angulos = [0, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 90]
senos_cossenos = [(round(sin(radians(item)), 3), round(cos(radians(item)), 3)) for item in angulos]
print(senos_cossenos)
```

17º Exemplo:

Se desejamos encontrar as `"raizes quadradas"` dos valores de outra lista, podemos utilizar o seguinte código...

```
from math import sqrt

valores = [2, 4, 9, 10, 16, 20, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121]
raiz_quadrada = [round(sqrt(item), 2) for item in valores]
print(raiz_quadrada)
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela ajuda.

Comment: Ok. Estamos aqui para compartilhar conteúdo de qualidade.