# Como esse trecho de código funciona?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Minha dúvida é mais precisamente na linha `"8"`, linha na qual contém o `for`. Nunca vi um for ser utilizado dessa forma. Eu entendi a lógica da linha, mas o funcionamento dessa iteração me deixou muito curioso.

```
import csv

%precision 2

with open('mpg.csv') as csvfile:
    mpg = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

sum(float(d['cty']) for d in mpg) / len(mpg)
```

Comment: maneira pythonica de fazer o for em uma só linha, olha outro exemplo básico nesta resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%c3%a9-c%c3%b3digo-pyth%c3%b4nico/192388#192388)

Comment: A estrutura "for" do Python, ao mesmo tempo que é bem robusta, é altamente flexível. E, por isso aceita diversas formas de ser implementada. Esta é uma das maneiras pythonica de se implementar o for em uma só linha. Veja `outros` exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459254/d%c3%a1-para-fazer-o-for-em-1-linha/459263#459263)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A expressão do tipo

```
(func(e) for e in seq)
```

é chamada de **expressão de gerador** (ou *generator expression* em inglês). Ela é usada para criar uma sequência pegando os elementos de outra sequência e os modificando - nesse caso, **pegando cada elemento `e` de `seq` e passando-os pela função `func`**.

Note que o objeto retornado é um tipo de **iterável** (mais especificamente, um objeto do tipo gerador):

```
strings = ['1', '2', '3']
nums = (int(s) for s in strings)
print(nums)  
# output: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8565e11200>
```

Os geradores têm algumas propriedades especiais que não vem ao caso agora; resumidamente, você pode iterar sobre eles uma única vez, e para fazer uma nova iteração é necessário recriá-lo, pois ele é "consumido".

A função `sum` aceita qualquer tipo de iterável, incluindo geradores. Portanto, ao escrever algo como

```
strings = ['1', '2', '3']
nums = (int(s) for s in strings)
sum(nums)
```

estou somando todos os elementos dentro do iterável (gerador) `nums`.

E note também que não preciso necessariamente definir a variável `nums`. É possível construir o gerador e consumi-lo em uma mesma linha:

```
strings = ['1', '2', '3']
sum(int(s) for s in strings)
```

A última minha converte todos os elementos da sequência `strings` para inteiros e os soma, de uma vez só. Nesse caso não é estritamente necessário utilizar parênteses ao redor da expressão de gerador por uma mera questão de simplificação de sintaxe que Python permite.

Se você fosse tentar replicar esse comportamento com um for loop "tradicional", faria algo do tipo:

```
strings = ['1', '2', '3']
nums = []
for s in strings:
    n = int(s)
    nums.append(n)
sum(nums)
```

O que é bem menos prático, na minha opinião. (E não é estritamente equivalente, uma vez que `nums` agora é uma lista, e não um gerador, mesmo que o resultado final seja idêntico).