# "List Comprehensions" vale a pena?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

O uso de *List Comprehensions* em Python é um bom uso? Afeta a performance do programa (tempo de execução, etc..)?

Alguns exemplos:

```
# Lista com números pares de 0 a 10:
par = [x for x in range(11)  if x % 2 == 0]
    
# Mostra no terminal os números pares de 0 a 10:
[print(x) for x in range(11)  if x % 2 == 0]
```

Por exemplo, no segundo caso estou criando uma lista (não armazenando ela) só para mostrar no terminal os valores, porém essa lista fica `[none, none..]` (acrescenta um `none` a cada impressão)

Seria melhor usar o jeito tradicional, deixando de criar uma lista com valores nulos (apesar de não armazenar ela em uma variável) ou não faz diferença?

```
# Código tradicional no segundo caso:
for x in range(11):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Se for **só** pra imprimir, não vale a pena, pois estará criando uma lista à toa, sem contar que acho gambiarra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/459289/112052 - Agora se precisa criar uma lista com os valores, ai a diferença *provavelmente* será pequena, mas desempenho é algo que tem que ser analisado caso a caso. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108488

Comment: Obr por essas perguntas, tb me ajudou!!

Comment: Dá para fazer em uma linha sem ter que gerar uma lista `for x in range(11): print(x) if x % 2 == 0 else None` mas é uma gambiarra pois é um uso torto da [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O uso de List "Comprehensions" em Python eh um bom uso?

Sim, é um bom uso. A ideia principal sempre foi deixar
as coisas mais legíveis e concisas - então, a não ser que
seja uma expressão complexa, que fique mais legível em
múltiplas linhas, seu uso é recomendado - os casos
mais simples de list-comprehensions trocam 3 ou 4
linhas de código por uma única linha com menos
de 60 colunas. Vale muito a pena.

> Afeta a
> performance do programa (tempo de execução, etc..)?

A diferença é mínima - mas se a ideia é criar uma lista,
as list-comprehension são um pouco mais rápidas
do que criar uma lista vazia e ir fazendo append -
só por que o construtor da lista executa o iterador
do "for" direto em código nativo - sem uma chamada
ao ".append" pra cada elemento.

Essa diferença é realmente mínima, e não vai ser sentida
pra listas de 10, 100 ou 200 elementos, ou trechos de código
que sejam executados uma única vez.

Pra listas maiores, em um trecho de programa que rode
constantemente (por exemplo, em uma view de uma aplicação
web com vários acessos concorrentes), pode começar
a fazer diferença real.

Já o uso que você faz, para fazer o "print", realmente não é
o mais usual - normalmente se usa list-comprehension quando
você quer os valores mesmo. **Mas** quando estamos no modo interativo
(seja no ipython, em um notebook, ou no pdb), essa sintaxe pod ser um bom atalho
pra ver o conteúdo de várias coisas - e aí não há contra-indicações.

Mesmo que fosse uma lista com algumas dezenas de milhares de elementos "None",
a diferença de performance/consumo de memória para uma única execução sequencial
é negligível, quando comparamos o tamanho dessa estrutura com todo o processo
da app Python, que inclui o runtime do cpython: não vai fazer nem cócegas

Apesar disso, é importante ter em mente que uma construção muito parecida com
as list-comprehensions, as "generator expressions", funcionam de forma muito mais racional nesse sentido - é a mesma coisa, mas sem ser delimitada por `[` e `]`, e sim, só por parênteses (e as vezes até sem nada, se o contexto permitir).

As generator expressions só avançam um passo no seu "for" quando um elemento vai ser "consumido" por uma estrutura de fora delas- e não guardam o elemento - então não há esse "gasto" de memória.

Só que uma generator expression sozinha também não é executada - alguém tem que "consumir" seu conteúdo.

Ou seja:

```
(print(x) for x in range(11) if x % 2 == 0)
```

não faz nada: o Python prepara o objeto, pronto
para criar os valores de x e chamar o "print", mas enquanto
um `for` ou uma outra função para onde você passar essa
generator expression como parâmetro não consumir os valores,
o `for` nunca avança e o print não é executado. (A função "next" avança um generator de 1 em 1 se alguém optar por fazer o que o `for` faz manualmente)

Por exemplo, a função `any` espera um iterável, e ela consome
todos os valores até chegar no primeiro que não seja equivalente
a um "False" booleano. Como o "print" retorna "None", ela consumiria
isso até o final:

```
any(print(x) for x in range(11) if x % 2 == 0)
```

(perceba também que se não houver ambiguidade, não é preciso
por um par de parenteses exclusivo para a generator expression, como mencionado acima).

Um padrão de uso mais comum é, em vez de colocar o print dentro
da estrutura de repetição, manter a estrutura de repetição só gerando
os valores desejados, e passa-la como parâmetro para o método `join`
de uma string, que já cuida da formatação.

O único detalhe é que cada elemento de um iterador que o "join" consome
tem que ser uma string.

Mas, resumindo, isso aqui é considerado de "boa qualidade" para
estar em código de produção (embora isso seja um pouco subjetivo):

```
print(", ".join(str(x) for x in range(11) if not x % 2))
```

E só pra manter a resposta completa, é importante lembrar que também
existem os "dict comprehension": `{chave: valor for chave, valor in iteravel}` e os "set comprehensions": `{elemento for elemento in iteravel}` -
as mesmas ideias se aplicam para ambos.

Comment: Muitíssimo obr, tirou todas as minhas dúvidas!! Vlw mesmo!

Answer (score 5):

Python é uma linguagem lenta e as pessoas trabalham com isso, então esse preocupação não é tão importante. Se a performance for tão importante assim é caso de usar outra linguagem.

O mecanismo em si não é caro então não deve ter medo de usá-lo para fazer o que ele costuma ser útil que é criar uma lista nova de forma simplificada.

Não deve fazer isso só para economizar digitação ou em alguns casos nem isso.

A criação de uma lista quando não precisa de uma é bastante ineficiente. Se for um *script* mesmo, na maioria das vezes, não importa muito. Se estiver fazer mais que isso e a lista for grande pode ser um exagero fazer o código que fez porque ele cria uma lista sem necessidade e sem ganho algum.

O que poderia dizer é que ficou em uma linha, e acho uma falha da linguagem não permitir isto (colocando a forma declarativa para comparar e mostrar que fica igual):

```
for x in range(11): if x % 2 == 0: print(x)
[print(x) for x in range(11) if x % 2 == 0]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ListComprehensions.py).

Fizeram uma exceção no compilador para não aceitar isso, ou seja, deliberadamente escolherem que isso não fosse aceito por causa da filosofia "só ter uma forma de fazer" que sempre é violada, mas esse caso que havia vantagens ter outra forma não aceitaram.