# dois for numa mesma linha dentro de uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

galera estou lendo o livro *python fluente* do luciano ramalho e logo no inicio me deparo com uma instrução a qual nunca tinha visto e não consigo achar nenhuma informação sobre ela. A instrução é a seguinte:

```
self.cards = [Card(rank,suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
```

eu não consigo, achar uma explicação do porque ter dois for numa mesma linha e ainda dentro de uma lista. Eu só preciso entender essa parte do for o resto ta tranquilo. Tem como alguem dar uma ajuda ??

Comment: Acesse este link [Dá pra fazer o for em 1 linha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459254/d%c3%a1-para-fazer-o-for-em-1-linha/459263#459263)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é chamado de list comprehension, tem como função minimizar linhas de código e deixar o código mais 'pythonico'. Para explicar melhor, essa mesma variável poderia ser escrita assim:

```
# instanciação da var
self.cards = []
# para cada suit na var self.suits
for suit in self.suits:
    # para cada rank na var self.ranks
    for rank in self.ranks:
        # isntancia um Card e coloca na var self.cards
        self.cards.append(Card(rankd, suit))
```

No list comprehension você tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
# x = var saída da iteração que foi passada dentro da estrutura for
# for x in range(0,10) = estrutura for padrão
lista = [x for x in range(0,10)]
```

E ai você pode aplicar essa regra em objetos mais complexos, como é o caso seu, onde você tem uma lista de um objeto Card

```
# Card(rank, suit) = resultado final dos for realizados, como é mostrado no exemplo com for padrão
self.cards = [Card(rank,suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
```