# Como fazer quebra de linha no print de uma lista em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Minha dúvida é como fazer a quebra de linha em um print de uma lista no Python.
preciso fazer um print do código funcionando. Só que os nomes da lista estão ficando muito extensos.
A cada 10, o ganhador ganha 1 cupom, então se ele doa 100 o nome dele entra 10 vezes na lista, fazendo uma linha enorme tem como fazer uma quebra de linha no print?

```
listasorteio = []

while True:
    print('digite sair para encerrar')
    nome = input('digite o nome: ')
    if nome == 'sair':
        break
    valordoado = int(input('Digite o valor doado: '))
    valord = valordoado // 2
    listasorteio.extend([nome]*valord)
print(listasorteio)
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [Compreensão de listas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista) para chamar a função `print` em cada elemento da lista:

```
[print(nome) for nome in listasorteio]
```

Como a função `print` já contém a quebra de linha, deve retornar o resultado desejado.

Para maiores informações sobre compreensão de lista, aqui no site existe [bastante material](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Compreens%C3%A3o+de+lista+%5Bpython%5D) sobre o assunto.

Comment: isso aí amigo, deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: @OldSchoolGamer De nada. Se a resposta lhe serviu, não esqueça de aceitá-la para ajudar futuras buscas no site.

Comment: @OldSchoolGamer Se vc só queria imprimir os nomes, um em cada linha, é muito mais simples fazer `for nome in listasorteio: print(nome)`. Usar *list comprehension* nesse caso é um exagero, sem contar que com isso é criada uma outra lista desnecessariamente - os colchetes em volta da expressão criam uma lista. Se quer apenas imprimir e nada mais, pra que criar essa lista, sendo que dá pra imprimir tudo sem criá-la? Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/459289/112052

Comment: certo, entendi e funcionou bem também, Obrigado mesmo.